# Issues with entire column being zero in gnuplot histogram

Tags: undefined, gnuplot, histogram

I'm using gnuplot to create a stacked histogram.  Today, for the first time, all data points in one of the columns are zero.  This creates a problem for gnuplot, as it now reports:

> All points in histogram UNDEFINED

This is because my "using" statement has logic like:

> using ($6>0:$6:NaN)

When an entire column consists of ignored values, gnuplot chokes.  Is there a setting I can use to let gnuplot it should ignore this particular, and harmless issue?  There will be times when the column will be zero, and this is a valid condition in the data.  I'd like gnuplot to be able to handle this.

If I can't get gnuplot to handle it, I may have to issue my plot using commands differently to omit the missing dataset.  I'd really rather not make this change unless I must.

Anyone out there have any suggestions?

EDIT (Adding plotscript and data file):

The plotscript and data file are generated at run time, using a combination of a template file, and script logic to determine the final script.  This is fed directly to gnuplot by opening a command pipline to the gnuplot command and feeding the script directly to gnuplot.

The issue occurs today because column 6 in the graph is all zeros today.  This is a good thing (no images took longer than 60 minutes to process).  I would expect gnuplot to simply suppress the zero values (per the trinary operator in the 'plot' line in the plotscript), and if all values are suppressed, then there no data for that column of the histogram.  Normal and expected; except gnuplot doesn't like it.

Plotscript:

```
set terminal 'pngcairo'
set key center under horizontal font ",8"
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill  solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set xtics border in scale 0.5,0.25 nomirror rotate by 45  font ",8" offset character -2, -1, 0 right
set xtics autofreq  norangelimit
set ytics border in scale 0.5,0.25 nomirror norotate  font ",8" offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set ytics autofreq  norangelimit
set y2tics border in scale 0.5,0.25 nomirror norotate  font ",8" offset character 0, 0, 0 autojustify
set y2tics 1800  norangelimit
set my2tics 6
set title "Image Processing Trends"
set title  offset character 0, 0, 0 font ",18" norotate
set timestamp "" bottom offset character 0,-2,0
unset xlabel
set ylabel "Nbr of Images (bars)"
set ylabel  offset character 2, 0, 0 font ",8" textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set y2label "Avg Time in Seconds (line)"
set y2label  offset character 0, 0, 0 font ",8" textcolor lt -1 rotate by -270
set zero 1e-08
set label "Generated by Luna" font ",6" tc rgb "#808080" at graph 1,-0.25 right
plot 'datafile' using (sum [i=2:4] column(i)):xtic(1) title "< 15 min" lc rgb "#00FF50", '' using ($5>0?$5:NaN) title columnhead lc rgb "#F0F000", '' using ($6>0?$6:NaN) title columnhead lc rgb "#FF0000"


Datafile:
"Date" "< 5 min" "5 - 10 min" "10 - 15 min" "15 - 60 min" "> 60 min" "Avg ET"
  2012-10-26  1099    71    23     0     0   184
  2012-10-29    16     0     0     0     0    81
  2012-10-30     5     0     0     0     0    76
  2012-10-31   650    41    24    19     0   176
  2012-11-01   831   118    11     0     0   169
  2012-11-02   671   158   195    91     0   353
  2012-11-05   887   127    64    81     0   287
  2012-11-06  1343    35     8     0     0   139
  2012-11-07  1018   233   201   112     0   334
  2012-11-08  1140   433   143    16     0   271
  2012-11-09  1192   115    15     0     0   168
  2012-11-12  1008    90    17     1     0   173
  2012-11-13   911    62     5     0     0   160
  2012-11-14  1066   346   219    68     0   317
  2012-11-15   754   110     0     0     0   170
```

Comment: What version of gnuplot?  Do you have access to gnuplot 4.6?

Comment: gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 1

Comment: Can you show the plotscript your working with and a sample datafile? (if it's not too long?).  Also, what do you want gnuplot to plot if there is no usable data?

Comment: The plotscript is actually generated by a Perl program, but it is built using templates and other statements. I will attempt to construct what is programmatically fed to gnuplot by the script.  I have added both the plotscript and data file to the original question text.

Comment: I created a workaround for this, but I would still like to know if there is a better answer.  Since the plotscript is generated, I added logic to only include a "using" section for a column if valid data was detected in at least one row of that column.  This seems to be enough to keep gnuplot from screaming about it.  I would like to not have to resort to such trickery, so if someone has a better answer, I'm anxious to hear it.

Comment: I haven't really had a moment to think about this/examine your plot script -- And I'm not sure when I'll get to it.  When I do have some time I'll try to think something up and let you know if nobody's answered by then.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that for some reason gnuplot treats differently `NaN` and `1/0`, the mathematically undefined expression that gets *silently ignored* (see for example the remark [here](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.0/gnuplot.html)). Using `NaN` in your logic for your column 6 with all zeros will produce an error

```
 "<scriptname>", line xx: All points in histogram UNDEFINED
```

and an empty png file. Bummer. However `1/0` in your logic will produce just a warning

```
 "<scriptname>", line xx: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

and it will produce the plot with the rest of the data. As it is skipping the data set completely, " > 60 mins" will not appear in the legend either, which you may want.

So just change your logic for column 6 (and 5 too, if it ever becomes full of zeros) in the plot command to

```
plot 'datafile' using (sum [i=2:4] column(i)):xtic(1) title "< 15 min" lc rgb "#00FF50", '' using ($5>0?$5:1/0) title columnhead lc rgb "#F0F000", '' using ($6>0?$6:1/0) title columnhead lc rgb "#FF0000"
```

Other than the warning message informing you about no data to plot for >60 mins (which we know to begin with), this should work.

I used gnuplot v4.6 patchlevel 0.